# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Youhave an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I use MySQL, why MariaDB in the error message? I have tried replacing the parameters `? by known values and it worked. The problem is in the
"?" as a placeholder for parameters 1 and 2 in the code

```
try {
            

             //THE ISSUE IS HERE!
            String sql = "Select * From dusuario Where nome_usuario= ? and senha_usuario= ?"; 
            
            
            PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            

            
            pstm.setString(1, usuarioDTO.getNome_usuario()); 
            pstm.setString(2, usuarioDTO.getSenha_usuario()); 
            
            
            ResultSet resultado = pstm.executeQuery(sql);
            
            return resultado;
            
        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na classe UsuarioDao: "+ erro);
            
            return null;
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add quotation marks: `String sql = "Select * From dusuario Where nome_usuario= '?' and senha_usuario= '?'";`

Comment: @Christian that would defeat part of the purpose of using prepared statements.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Of course, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ResultSet resultado = pstm.executeQuery(sql);
```

In the above line you doesn't need to pass `sql` String again as it is already assign to the `pstm` object and the values are updated using `setString()`

So, the line can ne rewritted as

```
ResultSet resultado = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using prepared statements you need to call [`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) without passing any parameter, so

```
ResultSet resultado = pstm.executeQuery();
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) of the parametrized version:

> **Note**:This method cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.